# autowrapper response contains extra wrapping

Tags: asp.net-core

i am using Autowrapper and in my program.cs ihave this setup

```
var app = builder.Build();
//app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
//app.UseApiResponseAndExceptionWrapper<MapResponseObject>();
app.UseApiResponseAndExceptionWrapper();
 app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
```

app.Run();

the controller code looks like this

```
        [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetLast12MonthBalances")]
    public async Task<ApiResponse> GetLast12MonthBalances()
    {
        try
        {
            return new ApiResponse("My Custom Message.",await _transactionService.GetLast12MonthBalances(null));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApiException(ex);
        }
    }
```

i am expecting it to return

```
{
 "version": "1.0.0.0",
"statusCode": 200,
"message": "My Custom Message.",
"isError": null,
"responseException": null,
"result": { //my object
```

but it is wrapping the result in another result property

```
{
 "message": "GET Request successful.",
 "result": {
 "version": "1.0.0.0",
 "statusCode": 200,
 "message": "My Custom Message.",
 "isError": null,
 "responseException": null,
 "result": { // my object
```

"message": "GET Request successful." should not be there since i am passing custom message

what am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in the latest release. Please try to use `v.4.5.0` and it should fix it.

Program.cs:

```
using AutoWrapper;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseApiResponseAndExceptionWrapper();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

API Controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = "GetPeopleById")]
public ApiResponse GetById(int id)
{
    var people = GetPeople();
    var person = people.Where(o => o.Id == id);

    if (person.Any())
    {
        return new ApiResponse("Hey", person, 200);
    }

    throw new ApiException("Not Found!");
}

private static IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
{
    var list = new List<Person>();
    list.AddRange(
         new Person[]
         {
             new Person { Id = 1, FirstName= "Vynn", LastName = "Foo"},
             new Person { Id = 2, FirstName= "Vjor", LastName = "Foo"},
             new Person { Id = 3, FirstName= "Vianne", LastName = "Foo"}
         });

    return list;
}
```

Sample Output:

```
{
  "message": "Hey",
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "Vynn",
      "lastName": "Foo"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: yes latest version 4.5.1 has this bug. using 4.5.0 will showing correctly.

Comment: Confirmed, version 4.5.1 started double-wrapping responses on our project as well. It's been several months by now, yet no word on whether this is going to get fixed so far. Perhaps team AutoWrapper doesn't consider it a bug.